# How to transpose an ER-Diagram?

Tags: mysql, sql, transpose, diagrams, erd

I have some trouble transposing an ER-Diagram. I understand how to start but I am not sure transpose the diamonds for example the one say "contains" and how to go about the conductor. If I could get some advice it would be greatly appreciated.

So far this is what I have:

```
Concert Season(season_year*,closing_date,opening_date)

Concert(concert_number*, name,date,time)

Composition(composer_name,composition_name*,num_movements)

 Member(city,state,zipcode,street,firstname,lastname,middle_inital,lastname,memberID*,musician,conductor)
```

Diagram is linked here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFRrv.jpg